# MongoDB geospatial query with $not

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a basic geospatial query working well in MongoDB. It seems that it should be easy to apply $not to get the complement... but it's not working for me. Is it simple user error? Or can MongoDB not handle this query conceptually? I could not find any such limitation in the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing).

Working query (correctly finds the 2 cities within 10 miles of the center):

```
db.customers.find({ "location" : { $within : { $center : [[-117.15,32.72],0.15] } } })
```

Attempted complement query (desired result is the 1 city that is not within 10 miles):

```
db.customers.find({ "location" : { $not : { $within : { $center : [[-117.15,32.72],0.15] } } } })
error: {
    "$err" : "missing geo field (location) in : {location: { $not: { $within: { $center: [ [ -117.15, 32.72 ], 0.15 ] } } } }",
    "code" : 13042
}
```

For anyone that wants to copy/paste the query to see the error, here's a tiny bit of sample data:

```
db.customers.ensureIndex( { "location" : "2d" } )
db.customers.save({"city":"La Mesa","state":"CA","location":[ -117.02,32.76 ]})
db.customers.save({"city":"Chula Vista","state":"CA","location":[ -117.08,32.63 ]})
db.customers.save({"city":"Mexico City","state":"Mexico","location":[-99.133244,19.4326]})
```

(I'm using MongoDB 1.8.2 in case that matters.)

Comment: that's a tough one... I'd also recommend a message on the mongodb-user google group...

Comment: Yeah, i'd also recommend it.. its a nice question..

Comment: A query like this is not possible, but it's a known enhancement request. For future reference, these threads on the MongoDB Google Group discuss the issue. 
[Geo Query using $and][1] 
[Geo Query][2]


[1]: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/4417b0f9f0b3de12
[2]: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/65a7fd77a2ee4306

Help! I can't figure out how to format these links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is not possible. As far as I know, location queries will give you a special cursor that can only use location queries as parameters (such as `$within`).

v. 2.0.1 gives a more descriptive error message: 
 `error: { "$err" : "geo field only has 1 element", "code" : 13068 }`

The issue with indexing is that, in general, negation is *EVIL*. Most indexes don't cope well when you turn them around, so even if your query worked, it's probably not desirable because it will probably have to do a table scan.

I'm not entirely sure about this, a message to the newsgroup is probably a good idea.

Comment: Yes, a posting to the newsgroup helped. Others have similar requests. Support for $or and $all are perhaps more useful (less EVIL), but they are not supported either. The improvement is requested here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3984

Comment: I Like mongodb scheduled    Due:Dec 31 2012 UTC