# Mongodb not $near

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation

Let's say I have a collection in mongoDB with geoLocation indexed field (coordinates).
I know I can query records nearby my location with something like

`MySchema.find({coordinates: {$near: [100,100], $maxDistance: 500}, callback);`

But what if I want to get those records away from my location (out of the circle around location)?? Is it possible? I have tried to use `$not`, but it returned empty results, but I know there are hundreds of records not near me.

I know there is this option to get nearby records, then select the ones `{_id: {$not: {$in: nearby_ids_array}`. But is it the only way, or am I missing something???

Comment: I know this might not be a wise thing to do, but maybe you could try using negative values for $maxDistance. The behaviour of using negative numbers is undocumented.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126041/mongodb-geospatial-query-with-not.

Comment: Ok it's not possible. I got it :)