# Convert latitude longitude type in mongodb in order to perform geospatial queries

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, geospatial

I have documents in mongodb containing:

```
{
    "Latitude" : "1.242",
    "Longitude" : "-12.311"
}
```

That's right they are strings! How to I convert them into double type and store them as Geoson points i.e.

```
{
    "Coordinates" = [-12.311,1.242]  
}
```

I want to be able to perform geospatial queries of the form.

```
"$and":[{"Latitude" : { "$not" : { "$within" : { "$center" : [[lat,lon]],1000] } } }},{"Longitude" : { "$not" : { "$within" : { "$center" : [[lat,lon],1000] } } }}]
```

A query of the form
[Mongodb not $near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831402/mongodb-not-near)
Find all points not within the circle of radius 1000 metres formed by lat lon.Can it be done without the change? If yes then please suggest something else. Please help!

Comment: What  the documents should look like after the query? `{ "Coordinates": [-12.311, 1.242] }`?

Comment: @SSDMS That's right

Comment: @SSDMS I basically want to be able to perform geospatial queries on it.

Comment: The new structure of your documents is not valid. Do you need to "keep" the "Latitude" and "Longitude" fields?

Comment: I basically want to perform that query. If it is possible with the original "Latitude" and "Longitude" fields, great! Else, I wish to convert it into a form in which I can easily get all the points outside a radius.

Comment: Please help if you can. I've been stuck on this query for quite a long time!

Comment: @SSDMS A query along these lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831402/mongodb-not-near

Comment: @SSDMS How is the new structure invalid btw. I've used a query to get the **Coordinates** field from **Latitude** and **Longitude**. My basic purpose is to be able to perform geospatial queries. I will be able to with the Coordinates data structure, right?

Comment: Do you simply want to change the documents structure so that you can perform the geospatial queries or there is something else?

Comment: @SSDMS That's right!

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Coll.aggregate(
           [
{$addFields:    {"coordinates" :  ["$latitude" ,"$longitude"] }     },
{$out:"coll_new"}
            ]           
            );
```